# How to bind a static IP for a container group on ACI using Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, reverse-proxy, azure-container-instances

I've a docker compose file intended to run on Azure Container Instance.
Its composed of 3 containers (django, nginx, certbot). I would like to bind a static public IP to the container. I can create it at a runtime but would like to bind the public IP beforehand so I can set the DNS A record for the reverse proxy to negotiate it's SSL certificate. Is there a way to do it by using the Docker compose script or Do I have to use another way like the YML or Resource Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Docker's documentation for their integration with Azure Container Instances, the scope of the features that are implemented in their integration seems to be quite limited and networking related configurations aren't covered. It seems only the port configuration and DNS labels are available (network related features) as described here: [ACI integration Compose features | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-compose-features/)

This means that any other features will need to be implemented using other methods such as YAML files, ARM or Bicep templates, etc. (methods that implement the whole ACI API)

It is worth noting that you can't specify a static public IP directly with the other methods either, but you can specify a DNS label and the DNS name will be persisted throughout the ACI's lifecycle (therefore always reachable via the same name) even if the IP changes.

Having a static IP requires leveraging an application gateway, for instance, which can have a static public IP in front of the ACI (which could then be exposed privately on a selected VNet).

Reference documentation for the above:
[Static IP address for container group - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway)